# Накладываются элементы flex-контейнера друг на друга

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, flexbox

Приветствую! Верстаю меню с помощью `flexbox` и столкнулся с проблемой, что если я поставлю `flex-wrap: wrap;`, то элементы наслаиваются друг на друга. Это скорее всего из-за `padding`'а у моей ссылки, как это исправить? Вот код:

Так выходит:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  font-family: Arial;}
html {
  height: 100%; 
  unicode-bidi: embed;
  direction: ltr;}
body {
  background-color: #6C238D;}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4F1373;
  padding: 10px 0px;}
.menu ul {display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;}
.menu ul li {flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;}
.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EAE6E6;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  background-color: #37196F;
  border: 2px outset #301B4F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
   -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
   -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);  
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
 }
  
.menu li a:hover {
  color: #BE962F;
  border: 2px inset #301B4F;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">This page</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Another page</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">And another page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

А по дефолту так: 
[image: flexbox]

Хотелось бы, чтоб оно ровненько подвинулось вниз, при уменьшении экрана, а выходит так:
[image: flexbox2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда инлайн-элементам добавляется паддинг, то это не влияет на их «внешнюю коробку» и из-за этого они могут налазить друг на друга. Тут достаточно добавить ссылкам стиль `display: inline-block`.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  font-family: Arial;}
html {
  height: 100%; 
  unicode-bidi: embed;
  direction: ltr;}
body {
  background-color: #6C238D;}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4F1373;
  padding: 10px 0px;}
.menu ul {display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;}
.menu ul li {flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;}
.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EAE6E6;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  background-color: #37196F;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px outset #301B4F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
   -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
   -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);  
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 3px rgba(48,17,48,0.67);
 }
  
.menu li a:hover {
  color: #BE962F;
  border: 2px inset #301B4F;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">This page</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Another page</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">And another page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. помогло.